# Google Sheets onEdit function: when checkboxes are true clear rows on a different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets. In the first one "Generale" there are 5 columns with only checkboxes.
The next sheets all refer to Generale using these formulas:

```
=QUERY(Generale!$A$1:$Y$31;"SELECT A, B, C, D, E WHERE H = TRUE")
=QUERY(Generale!$A$1:$Y$31;"SELECT A, B, C, D, E WHERE I = TRUE")
=QUERY(Generale!$A$1:$Y$31;"SELECT A, B, C, D, G, F WHERE J = TRUE")
=QUERY(Generale!$A$1:$Y$31;"SELECT A, B, C, D WHERE K = TRUE")
=QUERY(Generale!$A$1:$Y$31;"SELECT A, B, C, D WHERE L = TRUE")
```

When I check a box in Generale (e.g. H2), values A2, B2, C2, D2, E2 get copied in the second sheet, then in F2, G2 and H2 I write other data.
When I uncheck the box in Generale!H:2, all the corresponding values in the second sheet are cleared, while F2, G2 and H2 are not.

This way if I then check a different box, I have to manually clear those other columns or the data in F2,G2,H2 will be associated to the wrong items.

Is there a way to use onEdit to clear the corresponding F,G,H values (not the whole columns)?

Thanks for any help!

Some pictures of the issue I'm facing:

[1 - General tab with the checkboxes (notice the EM column with 3 checkboxes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOWJt.png)

[2 - EM tab with only the rows corresponding to the EM checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8830.png)

[3 - removing 1 checkbox from General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BAQS.png)

[4 - EM tab with wrong correspondence (since 1 row has been removed when the checkbox was ticked off)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evadM.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you explain your detailed question using the sample input and output situations you expect as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: @Tanaike I added the pictures. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the sample images. I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. When the checkbox is checked or unchecked, you want to change the sheets except for "Generale". You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, I have a question. For example, at the sheet "EM", where did the values of columns "F" to "I" come from? Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic for achieving your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike That's exactly my intent.

In EM the F, G, H and I columns are added by me:

- first I check a box in Generale.

- then I go to EM sheet and add data to F, G, H and I.


- When I need to clear the box (and the corresponding data) I uncheck the box in Generale, but in the EM sheet those columns (F, G, H and I) are not cleared because they are just plain text